# Drupal overwrite view default markup

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I am new in Drupal 8 and trying to build a custom theme. Overwriting a theme works well for paragraphs, blocks etc. but not for views. I need your help to tell me how to override the markup of a view. I already created a the .twig file in the custom folder and tested it. It works.

That's what I have inside:

```
{% for row in rows %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The `{{ row.content }}` gives me every element I need in the default Drupal view markup. I want to costumize the HTML. such as:

```
<h1 class="headline">
    {row.title}
</h1>
<p class="text">
    {row.text}
</p>
<img src="{row.image}" />
```

I didn't find a way to get the values such as the title from the `row`. I tried things like `row.{field_name}` or `row.content.{field_name}` but nothing works yet. Is there anyway to access these fields by machine name?

Comment: Have you read [debugging twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to display the contents would be to set the views to content list with a view mode. For e.g: If you want to display a node content type `article` with display mode `teaser` then you will get the `node--article--teaser.html.twig` getting rendered.
Then you can modify the the twig file in required format.

```
<h1 class="headline">
  {{ node.title.value }}
</h1>
<p class="text">
  {{ node.body.value }}
</p>
<img src="{{ node.field_image.entity.uri.value }}" />
```